# Django NestedHyperlinkedModelSerializer not returning Foreign Key Field

Tags: django, django-orm, django-serializer

Parent id or foreign key is not returning from child. I am trying [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) example.

***models.py***

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class MailDrop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ClientSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['id', 'name']


class MailDropSerializer(NestedHyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    parent_lookup_kwargs = {
        'client_pk': 'client_id',
    }

    class Meta:
        model = MailDrop
        fields = ['id', 'title']
```

**views.py**

```
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Client.objects.filter()
        serializer = ClientSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Client.objects.filter()
        client = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = ClientSerializer(client)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class MailDropViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = MailDropSerializer

    def list(self, request, client_pk=None):
        queryset = MailDrop.objects.filter(client_id=client_pk)
        serializer = MailDropSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, client_pk=None):
        queryset = MailDrop.objects.filter(pk=pk, client_id=client_pk)
        maildrop = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = MailDropSerializer(maildrop)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I add `fields = ['id', 'title', 'client_id']` in the `MailDropSerializer`, it throws the following error:

```
AssertionError: `NestedHyperlinkedRelatedField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `con
text={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.
```

If I add the request in the serializer context, the output is as follows:

```
url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/clients/4/maildrops/


[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Madison Mosley",
        "client_id": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/clients/4/"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Louis Chen",
        "client_id": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/clients/4/"
    }
]
```

I added the serializer context as follows:

```
def list(self, request, client_pk=None):
        queryset = MailDrop.objects.filter(client_id=client_pk)
        serializer_context = {
            'request': request
        }
        serializer = MailDropSerializer(
            queryset, many=True, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am trying to get something as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Madison Mosley",
        "client_id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Louis Chen",
        "client_id": 4
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved:

```
class MailDropSerializer(NestedHyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    parent_lookup_kwargs = {
        'client_pk': 'client_id',
    }

    client_id = IntegerField(source='client_id.id')


    class Meta:
        model = MailDrop
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'client_id']
```